# Getting `NoSuchMethodError` - while doing mongo connection

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

Background: Getting `NoSuchMethodError` - while doing mongo connection.

This is spring application. If i remove mongo template code then with mongo client it is working fine but with mongo template it is failing.

Dependencies I have added in my pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code Snipet

```
    final ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(
            "mongodb://ssdsd:wewdsds:2323");
    final MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
                builder.enabled(true);
                builder.invalidHostNameAllowed(true);
            }).build();
    MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings);
    SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory factory = new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(client, "db");
    MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(factory);
```

Exception i am getting

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.util.Assert.noNullElements(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions$MongoConverterConfigurationAdapter.registerConverters(MongoCustomConversions.java:287)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions$MongoConverterConfigurationAdapter.from(MongoCustomConversions.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoCustomConversions.<init>(MongoCustomConversions.java:95)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:3015)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:225)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:210)
```

Updated for classpath dependancies:

```
spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar                                   
spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar                     
spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar           
spring-cloud-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar                             
spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar         
spring-context-5.3.24.jar                                       
spring-context-support-2.5.6.jar                                
spring-data-commons-2.7.6.jar                                  
spring-data-mongodb-3.4.6.jar                                   
spring-expression-5.3.24.jar                                   
spring-jms-2.5.6.jar                                            
spring-tx-5.3.24.jar                                            
spring-web-5.3.22.jar
```

Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Use a better version of spring, this version requires at least 5.3.22 you are using 3.0.2, which isn't compatible.

Comment: even after upgrading spring web version to 5.3.22, i am still facing same issue.

Comment: You shouldn't be **only** upgrading the spring-web dependency but **all** your spring dependencies, else you are mixing versions which will lead to issues. They should be the same for all `org.springframework` dependencies.

Comment: updated question with classpath dependencies

Comment: As I state you are mixing various versions(2.5.6, 5.3.22, 5.3.24 and earlier also 3.0.2). You also appear to be using Spring Boot, but those dependencies indicate you are doing a whole lot of weird things in your dependency management. So please add your full `pom.xml` so that can be improved. Feels like you are trying to work around the Spring Boot dependency management.